# Importing cloned Git repository in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

I am trying to create an Eclipse project from a cloned Git repository
I've cloned the repository from here:
https://github.com/nazgee/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension

I have an existing project AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension and I want to create one called AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension-nazgee with the newly cloned repository.

When I try File -> Import -> Projects from Git and I select the new repository, I am unable to. I get this message:

Some or all projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace.

I have the directories:
C:....AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension
C:....AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension-nazgee

Then I edit the .project file, changing:
AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension
to:
AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension-nazgeee
Also edited build.xml, adding -nazgee to project name

With this the error is now:
Invalid project description    org.eclipse.egit.ui
Invalid project description    org.eclipse.core.resources

Comment: Not a solution, but, going forward, you can clone projects into a specific directory by putting it at the end of the clone command - git clone git@github.com:myproject/physics notPhysics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it the other way around: rename your existing project in Eclipse and import the new one as you did.

Comment: That was a good idea, but it doesn't seem to work (surprisingly)  I get this error:  Invalid project description.  
C:\Word\eclipse\workspace\AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension-nazgee overlaps the location of another project:   'AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension-nazgee'

Comment: It imports if I do:  File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace